# Irreducibility of a polynomial over the field of rational complex functions

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials, splitting-field

Let $k=\mathbb{C}(t)$ be the field of rational functions over $\mathbb{C}$.

I want to show that $P(x)=x^2+t \in k[x]$ is irreducible over $k$, and further find the degree of the splitting field of $P(x)$ over $k$.

I know that there is not a 'one size fits all' method to show irreducibility and that there are many different irreducibility criterion, but I am not sure what to do here.

Are there any suggestions for what to do here? Thanks!

Comment: Eisenstein Criterion will do it for you.

Comment: Show that no rational function of $t$ when squared leads to $\pm t$ (using degree of polynomials). Thus $x^2\pm t$ is irreducible.

Comment: @Lubin I am not sure if we can use Eisenstein here, we do not know anything about $t$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Would you mind elaborating a bit here please? Thank you.

Comment: Take any member of $k$ ie a rational function of $t$, say, $f(t) /g(t) $ where $f, g$ are polynomials with complex coefficients. Then the equation $(f(t)/g(t))^2=\pm t$ ie $(f(t)) ^2=\pm t (g(t)) ^2$ leads to contradiction (LHS is of even degree and RHS of odd degree).